# Perl how to parse INI files that contains variables?

Tags: perl

An INI file can have variables inside it like:

```
[section1]
root=/path/to/dir
home=%(root)s/my_home_dir/
```

Now, the Perl library `Config::IniFiles` doesn't seems to parse it, it passes it as raw strings

```
my $result = tie %info, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => $ini_file );
```

In Python there's a similar package called `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser` - that won't convert the variables, but then you can use `ConfigParser.ConfigParser` and it will.

Is there something similar in Perl, or a fix to what I'm looking for ?

Comment: Config::General::Interpolated parse only variables from type: $variable or ${variable} while the INI file has "%(root)s" kind of a Python type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find an existing parser for the config file format you are using, you could simply use

```
sub get_conf {
   my ($hash, $key) = @_;
   my $val = $hash{key};
   return undef if !defined($val);

   $val =~ s{%\(([^()]*)\)}{ get($hash, $1) // "" }eg;
   return $val;
}

my $home = get_conf(\%conf, 'home');
```

Comment: works, even though I was looking for something more built-in in Perl, but thanks !

Comment: Config::IniFiles which you were using is not built-in in Perl